# Simple handling of incoming tcp

Tags: scala, apache-camel, netty, telnet

Starting with:

http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/camel-http

I have made a simple route:

```
import org.apache.camel.scala.dsl.builder.RouteBuilder
class SocketPost extends RouteBuilder {
  """netty:tcp://localhost:12000"""  ==> {
    id("hello socket")
    log("hello")
    to("http4:localhost:9000/")
  }
}
```

and added it:

```
context.setUseMDCLogging(true)
context.addRoutes(new SocketPost())
context.start()
```

I can telnet to localhost:12000 and type in some data and disconnect, but my google skills fails me as to how to process the data. I only get a log  when I connect:

```
09:48:43 DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.netty.DefaultServerPipelineFactory   Using OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor with core pool size: 16
```

otherwise all is silent. I would like the data typed in via telnet to be POSTED to localhost:9000 as in the tutorial.

Comment: set textline=true in the netty uri, to be text based. Read more on the netty docs: http://camel.apache.org/netty

Comment: That did it, thanks! if you post """netty:tcp://localhost:12000?textline=true""" I can select that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The netty component is not text based by default, but using java object serialization. That was because the other by older tcp components camel-mina had that default behavior, and we wanted netty be be similar.

So you need to configure the endpoint as text based by setting the option `textline=true`. You can find more details about this option at: http://camel.apache.org/netty